# How to create VMWare Player Image with linux as the OS

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

How can I create an image (.iso) that contains: 1. Base Ubuntu OS 2. Java, CXF + some more software

I want these bundled as one VMPlayer image. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way as you would a Windows one, however you will not be creating an ISO.

An ISO in its most basic form is a file representation of a disk.

What you will want to do is download Ubuntu and/or your other software and then from VMWare Player, create a new virtual machine and select the Ubuntu ISO file as the cd image.

Install it as normal and install all your other custom software, then you should notice that at the location of where you created the virtual machine, there should be at least:

A `VMDK` file - The virtual machine hard drive.

A `VMX` file - The virtual machine configuation file.

(There may be a few more).

You can distribute this folder and when people double click on the `VMX` file, they should be able to run your virtual machine in VMWare Workstation or VMWare Player.

Comment: At least in the old days, VMWare *Player* could not create VMDK images.  Only Server could do that.  Dunno if that has changed in the years since I switched to VirtualBox.

Comment: @CarlF It has, VMWare Player can now create new virtual machines as well as "play" them, despite its name - http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you simply download an Ubuntu virtual machine from the [VMWare Virtual Appliance Marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/) rather than bothering with an install.